# How can AbstractList class provide an implementation of the 'Iterator<E>' Interface if it doesnot implements the Interface 'Iterator<E>'?

Tags: java, collections, interface, iterator, implements

I am very new to Java collection framework,pardon me if this question sounds silly.

there is one method 'iterator()' specified in 'Iterable ' Interface which returns an 'Iterator ' over elements of type E now AbstractList  (abstract class) provided an implementation to this method and returns an 'Iterator' so my question is how can it can return an 'Iterator'   without implementing interface 'Iterator'?

References :

ArrayList :
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()

AbstractList:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#iterator()

Iterable:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()

Iterator:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html

My understanding:

as we know functional interfaces can be implemented without using 'implements' keyword i.e by the means of anonymous class and lambda Expression but the 'Iterator' Interface is not a functional interface so a class needs to implement it using a 'implements' keyword but here the 'AbstractList' class(abstract) implements it without using the 'implements' keyword?

Note that i am talking about 'Iterator' interface not 'Iterable' Interface ,in Interface 'Iterable ' there is one method 'iterator()'
whose declaration looks like following- " Iterator iterator() " and this method is implemented by AbstractList class, since it provided implementation to 'iterator()' method which means that it must have implemented Interface 'Iterator' because return type of method is 'Iterator' but AbstractList class doesnot 'implements' Interface Iterator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is not very Collections specific. Any class can, of course, provide an implementation for X without having the class itself implementing that interface:

```
public interface X {
  int getSize();
}

public class A {

  private List<String> internalList = new ArrayList<>();

  // ...      

  public X x() {
    return new X() {
      public int getSize() {
        return A.this.internalList.size();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

(Example could be shortened using Lambdas, and `A.this` also is not explicitly required, but to increase understandibility).

`AbstractList` does more or less the same: Its `iterator()` method returns an `Iterator` implementation **using methods of the AbstractList** to implement the methods from the `Iterator` interface.

More Collections-specific information: `AbstractList` **must not** implement the `Iterator` interface, as an `Iterator` is a stateful object which can be used to iterate over an arbitrary list of elements - once. As soon as it is at the end (i.e., `hasNext()` returns `false`), it cannot be used again. So, any `List` directly implementing the `Iterator` interface could only be iterated once.

That's why each call to `iterator()` on an `AbstractList` **returns a new object** - with a new state for iterating the list from the beginning to the end.

Comment: Thanks a TON for your response!!Just wanted to confirm one thing ,this sort of implementation of an interface is an example of implementation of interface using anonymus inner class? it may sound very silly but i am very new to Java so i need some help.

Comment: “*without implementing that interface*” is a misleading phrase. The anonymous inner class *does* implement the interface, just without the “`implements`” keyword. Besides anonymous inner classes or lambda expressions/method references, an interface could also be implemented by implementing another interface that `extends` the former or by using [`Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) There might be more possibilities…

Comment: @Holger you are absolutely right, I detailed that sentence a bit. And yes, there are lots of other options what could be done, but I think that would be a little bit of an overload here :-)

Comment: Maybe rephrase “*without having the class itself implementing that interface*” to “*without an explicit `implements` clause for the interface*”

Answer (score 1):

> so a class needs to implement it using a 'implements' keyword but here the 'AbstractList' class(abstract) implements it without using the 'implements' keyword?

The `AbstractList` does not have to explicitly implement `Iterable`, because its superclass is `AbstractCollection`, which implements the `Collection` interface. The `Collection` interface extends  `Iterable`, so (transitively) `AbstractList` and `ArrayList` both implement `Iterable`.

In other words we can say that a class implements an interface if

- any of its parent classes implement the interface
- or any of its implemented interfaces extend the interface in question
- (or the class itself directly implements the interface - trivial case)

Comment: Hii,Thanks for your answer altough i am talking about 'Iterator' interface not 'Iterable' Interface ,in Interface 'Iterable ' there is one method 'iterator()' whose declaration looks like following- " Iterator<T> iterator() " and this method is implemented by AbstractList class, since it provided implementation to 'iterator()' method which means that it must have implemented Interface 'Iterator<T>' because return type of method is  Interface 'Iterator<T>' but AbstractList class doesnot 'implements' Interface Iterator<T> ?

Comment: AbstractList does not implement Iterator. It implements Iterable. Which means it has an iterator() method which returns an Iterator. But the returned Iterator itself is not the ArrayList instance, but a custom iterator.